# How to convert .mp4v to .mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have two files: file.mp4 and file.mp4v
How to convert mp4v to mp4 using ffmpeg without loss quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ffmpeg` can read `file.mp4v` remux with:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4v -map 0 -c copy output.mp4
```

- `-map 0` selects all streams, otherwise the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will apply.
- `-c copy` is [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

Comment: Thanks. Do u know why my question on stackoverflow got -3 reputation?

Comment: @Nikto 1) It was off-topic for Stack Overflow which is supposed to be for programming questions only. In reality SO has become a general computing help site due to the high number of off-topic questions and the inability of the site to teach new users that it is only for programming questions. 2) Maybe some users thought it wasn't a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 3) It was crossposted to multiple Stack Exchange sites which is discouraged because it wastes effort by answerers.

Comment: I thought that i will work with mp4 files, but now i have understood that i will work with mp4v files. I have a few commands witch converts mp4 to avi and mov.
Ex: ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.avi.
if i add -map 0 in my commands, will my commands work without loss quality for mp4v?
For example, for converting mp4v to avi i will use his command:
 ffmpeg -i file.mp4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.avi

Comment: pls read my last comment

Comment: *"if i add -map 0 in my commands, will my commands work without loss quality for mp4v?"* `-map 0` has nothing to do with quality. It just selects all streams. You don't need to use `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`: you can just use `-c copy`. MP4 → AVI: success depends on if AVI supports the video and audio formats in your MP4. MOV likely will support them.

Comment: i have a few commands witch converts .mp4 to some extensions(.avi, .mov). Can i just use these commands to convert .MP4V to these extensions (.avi, .mov)?

Comment: @Nikto I'll assume your command are using `-c copy`/`-codec copy`/`-vcodec copy -acodec copy`/`-c:v copy -c:a copy`.You never showed the details of the MP4V files, so I don't know what's in them so can't give a direct yes/no answer. I can only say that it will work if the video/audio in the MP4V are compatible with AVI/MOV then it will work. It they are not compatible then ffmpeg will provide an error or your player/device will not support it.

Comment: Cool, if i don't get error, all will be ok?

Comment: @Nikto I guess so. I don't know anything about the other end of things: player/device, etc.

Comment: And mp4v files it's just a video files.

Comment: @Nikto Yeah, I assumed it was video. Showing the output of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4v` will clear up most of the guesswork.